# After validating & submitting form, reset form + change some css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onsubmit

I have a simple html contact form with validation check.

I would like to have some commands executed after a successful form submission. But the way I've set this whole thing up... I can't make it work.

HTML contact form:

```
<form id="mycontact_form" name="form_name" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="https://domain.tld/cgi-bin/sendformmail.pl">
```

validateForm.js:

```
function validateForm() {
  //validating input fields
  if (!valid){
    return false;
  } else {
    if(condition1 == true)
     {
        document.form_name.submit(); return;
     }
    else {
        // doing stuff to form content
        document.form_name.submit(); return;
    }
    }
}
```

When the submit button is pressed, the form is validated and will be submitted to the *perl script sendformmail.pl* which return a `HTML Status 204` so the user stays on this page and is not redirected (that's the only way I got this part to work).

Now what I would like to have after a successful submission is:

- clear/reset the form and
- some minor UI stuff: change background of 2 elements + placeholder/inner text of 2 input fields for thank you message.

But for example if I put `document.form_name.reset()` after the `document.form_name.submit()`, it's too fast. It resets the form before submissions. I also tried to call another (independent) function after the `validateForm()` in the `onsubmit` but that seems to be wrong (well, at least it's not working).

So I guess I need to put these 2 things (reset + CSS changes) in a separate function and call it after a successful form submission. 
But how, where and when?

I'm very interested to learn a simple yet effective solution. (but jQuery is also available)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your form part of the sendformmail.pl file?

Comment: The form is on the html web site. The perl script is there to evaluate the form data and send it as email.
I found the script [here](http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your email script is on the same domain as your contact form, try submitting it via ajax. Here's a simple jQuery example, which would be in your onsubmit handler:

```
if (valid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cgi-bin/sendformmail.pl",
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#mycontact_form").serialize()
    })
    .done(function() { // this happens after the form submit
        $("#mycontact_form")[0].reset();
    });
}

return false; // don't submit the form again non-ajax!
```

Otherwise, if on different domains, try setting the target of your form to the id of a hidden iframe on your page. Since this is cross-domain, you have no real way of knowing the result of the form submit due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can simply hope for the best and reset the form after X number of seconds:

```
if (valid) {
    $("#mycontact_form").submit();

    // clear form 3 seconds after submit
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#mycontact_form")[0].reset();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Both of these approaches keep the user on the same page without a refresh.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've tried your first idea.
It sends the email and then clears the form. 

**But** there is a problem that will confuse people:
The form has 3 fields: name, email and message (textarea). If a fields fails to validate because it's empty, the placeholder is changed to ("Please enter your [field name]" and it gets an error classe (red font color etc.). 

Now after sending and clearing the form with your code, the fields _name_ & _email_ show the failed placeholder _but no error class_.
Maybe because `return false` was returned? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try breaking out your validation function from the onsubmit handler if the return statement is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `beforeSend` with ajax instead of `done`. And instead of resetting the form I chose to clear the value of the input fields/textarea (there are only 3). I also included the preferred 'post-submission' style of the input fields/textarea in `beforeSend` to leave nothing to chance.
Anyway, thank you for helping me & pointing me in the ajax direction.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cgi-bin/sendformmail.pl",
    method: "POST",
    data: $("#mycontact_form").serialize()
      beforeSend : function (){
                    // clear value of input fields/textarea & disable them
                    // use placeholders for "Thank you." etc.
                         }
    });
```